# How to avoid service call more than once when called on ngoninit

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 tabs which are 3 different components with there services and on click of each tab a service call is made on page load i.e. ngoninit. The requirement is like once the tab data is loaded for 1st tab and i click on 2nd tab and then again if i click back to 1st tab then 2nd time service call should not be made. The data should be retained via 1st service call itself. How can i achieve it. please help

Comment: Are the components being destroyed when navigating between the tabs? The oninit call should only fire once per component unless they're being destroyed between switching tabs in which case I'd be curious how the tabs are being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of data in your service.
For eg you can use Behaviour Subject for that purpose.
If you find the data in subject, utilize it otherwise make an http call to populate it.
In your service do the following:

```
 public myData: BehaviorSubject<SomeType[]> = new BehaviorSubject<SomeType[]>([]);

    constructor(private storage: Storage) { 

    }

    load(): void {

        this.storage.get('myData').then((data) => {

            this.myData.next(data);

        });

    }
```

Subscribe the subject in component and check if it is having relevant data. Other wise do http call to load it.